# Do rules exist for creating wondrous items?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Are there any hard rules aside from the few examples given and "use your imagination" to build your own wondrous items?

Comment: I had meant both as I thought that IF there are any hard rules then they would be at the same place or even have the same rules so better to split it up into two questions one for artefacts and one for wondrous items?

Comment: splitted them up. I know of those two links (looked at them before I had asked the question that is how the question popped up if there is only a bit of text and description ffor artefacts and none for wondrous items or if there are somewhere hard rules to use)

Comment: Are you looking rules for the GM to use in designing new kinds of items, or for rules for characters to craft new kinds of items?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, RAW is existing for wondrous item creation.

For general information regarding item creation read the "[Magic Item Creation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation)" section. After that the "[Creating Wondrous Items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Wondrous-Items)" section of the pdfsrd may answer all your questions. This article also contains a link to a table called "[Estimating Magic Item Gold Piece Values](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values)" for estimation of prices in respect to the modifiers used and so on.